# Editing All Label Colors in WPF Applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, label

I am trying to figure out, how to edit all label colors in my WPF App.
 Hope I can get some **opinions** here.

**Scenario**

**Goal**

> Enable Theming for End User

**Question**

```
How to edit alle labels at once, Where the Color is bound to the Custom Color Resource
```

**Prerequisites**

> Custom Resource Color on all Labels

**Example**

```
<Label.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource CustomLabelColor}"/>
</Label.Foreground>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use DynamicResource in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomLabelColor" />

    <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CustomLabelColor}" />
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="fsdaf"></Label>
        <Label Content="fsdaf"></Label>
        <Label Content="fsdaf"></Label>
        <Label Content="fsdaf"></Label>
        <Label Content="fsdaf"></Label>
</StackPanel>
```

And set the color from code:

```
this.Resources["CustomLabelColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
```

Or to use Hexa:

```
this.Resources["CustomLabelColor"] = 
new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF00AAFF"));
```

Comment: This throws me an Exception: #FF00FFFF' is not a valid value for property 'Color

Comment: It is working for me pretty well. Are you using the predefined Colors class values or Color.From...() functions? If you want to use hexa codes try this: 
this.Resources["CustomLabelColor"] = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF00AAFF"));

Comment: Found it: Works with => this.Resources["CustomLabelColor"] = Colors.Aqua;

Comment: What if i want to acces it from another class?, this.resource is not known

Comment: Of course because of it is a Window.Resources but don`t worry you can crate <Application.Resources> also and it should be in an external file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CustomLabelColor}" />
   </Style>
```

Comment: This indeed edits All the labels, but i want to be able to edit the ones with the color resource

Comment: Also I need to be able to change it programmaticly